# How to calculate the height of a FontFamily in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, uwp

I would like to know how to calculate the height of a given `FontFamily` in a Window Universal Application.

In **UWP**, the `FontFamily` object has a `LineSpacing` property that makes it possible to calculate the max height to allocate all the glyphs of the font, but it's not available for UWP applications.

**NOTICE:** About the "duplicate claim", using a TextBlock to measure the height isn't an option for me. Apart from being an ugly trick, it uses a UI object to do it. In my case, I cannot do that because I'm making a GUI Framework myself. It would have no sense to rely on object inside the UWP framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TextBlock's Measure method to measure both width and height. It's kind of hacky but does the job.

```
private Size MeasureString(string textToMeasure, Size availableSize, double fontSize, string fontFamily)
{
    var tb = new TextBlock();

    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    tb.Text = textToMeasure;
    tb.FontFamily = new FontFamily(fontFamily);
    tb.FontSize = fontSize;
    tb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

    return new Size(tb.ActualWidth, tb.ActualHeight);
}
```

The trick here is to use an infinite size in the measure method to get the actual size.

Another viable option would be to user Microsoft's [Win2D UWP](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) library. It has a [CanvasFontFace](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasFontFace.htm) class that contains everything you're looking for. I haven't personally used it but it should work for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not an option for me. I'm creating a GUI framework and I cannot use any native control to calculate it.

Comment: @SuperJMN Makes sense. Looks like I edited my post just before you commented. I added another option that doesn't use any native controls.

Comment: OK! please, refer to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162481/how-to-calculate-the-height-of-a-fontfamily-with-win2d. It seems that class is used internally. I don't know how to use it, either :( I cannot instantiate it directly and the docs don't explain much.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll give it a look once I'm on my Windows computer.

Comment: Did you take a look? :) thanks!